# Storing keystores keyPassword and keyStorePassword on public version control server

Tags: intellij-idea, android-keystore

We’re developing a new android application in IntelliJ IDEA and use artifacts to simplify package signing process. The release **keystore** is located locally.
We are using a public VCS and we are worry about storing **keyPassword** and **keyStorePassword** on it.

We couldn’t find anything about the algorithm used to encrypt these values. So, we suppose it might be some vulnerability in storing them on a public server.

Is there anybody who knows some more details about that and give us an advice?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really have to version it? You could manually copy it on developer's workstations, and add it to your VCS's ignore list to avoid committing it.

Comment: I agree, it’s not too much file manipulation here, but I would prefer to keep it in the project in case it’s secure enough and share with the whole development team just the keystore. The most important thing is to keep password privacy. Are there any best practices that might be applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't recommend storing you Android artifacts with keystore passwords on the public VCS servers, I've outlined it in the [KB article](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067).

Encryption is used just to hide the password from the eyes, but it can be easily decrypted (code for encryption/decryption is public). This is done by intention, so that your CI server can build these artifacts (TeamCity should support it).

You can opt for sharing these artifacts only if you are not afraid that your keystore password will become public. If you are sure that the keystore itself is 100% secure and will not be available to public, making its password available would not heart, but it obviously increases the chances to leak your keystore some day together with the password and compromise the applications on Play Store.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your detailed explanation which helped us in confirming our guesses.